# relational comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, compare

I am confuse for these comparison and I don't know how can be happen.
in bottom code when I compare **x** and **y** for less than or great than, it return false but when I compare them with equals they return true!
do you know why this happen?

```
var x = { y: 10 };
var y = { y: 11 };

x < y;  // false
x == y; // false
x > y;  // false

x <= y; // true
x >= y; // true
```

Comment: When you compare object references like that, the objects are converted to the string `[object Object]` and  then compared as strings. That's true *except* in the case of `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x < y;  // false
x > y;  // false
```

When any operand of a relational operator is an object, it is converted to a primitive value. So in this case, both `x` and `y` are first converted to primitive values and then compared with each other.

Both `x` and `y` will be converted to primitive values by eventually calling `.toString()` method on each object which will return a string of the form: `[object Object]` and since both objects will be converted in this string form, `x < y` and `x > y` both evaluate to false because both strings, i.e. `[object Object]` are equal.

```
x == y; // false
```

This evaluates to false because when types of both operands of `==` operator are same, javascript performs strict equality comparison `===`, and as both objects are two separate objects in memory, they are not equal.

```
x <= y; // true
x >= y; // true
```

These both expressions evaluate to true because the following comparison

```
"[object Object]" == "[object Object]"
```

evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

now I understand how are **x <= y** and **y <= x** resulting in true however **x < y** and **x == y** and **x > y** are all false.
in continue of accepted answer I can say these happen because the spec says for **x <= y** , it will actually evaluate **y < x** first, and then negate that result. Since **y < x** is also false, the result of **x <= y** is true.